# Word that is used to describe a law or contract that could become too powerful because of vague wording

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word used to describe laws or contracts that have the potential to  become too powerful because of vague wording. At first I thought it was something like "overreaching" but looking up the meaning of that yields different results.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Much depends on whether the contract just happens to have that potential because of careless drafting, or it is deliberately so written for some ulterior purpose. Much also depends whether you want to argue that this renders the contract legally void/voidable, or merely that it renders it intuitively unfair. Chances are that you will get a better answer at the Law Stack Exchange than here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscionability An unconscionable contract

Comment: It is important to differentiate civil and criminal law.   The US Supreme Cort has invalidated statutes on the grounds of vagueness. There is no substitute for the word in this situation, although cases explain the doctrine.

Comment: Thank you very much, everybody, for your comments. It's my first time to see the word Unconscionability and looking up its definition, it seems a bit extreme. The word that I'm looking for is used like:

"I'm sorry, I cannot sign this contract because I think it is <word> because its scope, from my perspective, extends beyond what I believe are comfortable boundaries." (without implying that they are trying to deceive me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is [*overbroad*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overbroad).

Comment: You should include an appropriate dictionary definition/link for the suggested word.

Comment: Thank you! Looking up the meaning of overbroad in various sources, it looks like this is the word for me to use.

Answer (score 0):

According to this source ([Corporate/Commercial Law](https://www.mondaq.com/uk/contracts-and-commercial-law/168250/open-to-interpretation)) the term "*contract open to interpretation*" describes fully this sort of arrangement.

Another term is "*ambiguous contract*" ([Corporate Counsel Business Journal](https://ccbjournal.com/articles/how-courts-interpret-ambiguous-contracts)).

Those terms should not be confused with the term "*abusive contract*".

> ([LegalMatch](https://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/abusive-contracts.html)) A contract may be deemed abusive under a few different types of contract theories. The main reason a contract might be abusive is that it is “unconscionable”. This means that the contract is so one-sided that it would be unjust for one of the parties to perform their duties.
>
> A contract can be unconscionable if it involves duress, undue influence, or unequal bargaining power. Most abusive contracts are unconscionable because of unequal bargaining power- one party took advantage of the other party’s lack of knowledge, experience, or resources.

There seems to exist no term to refer specifically to a contract that would confer too much power to one of the parties through the bias of the vagueness of its wording; however, if we give the idea a second's thought, it is readily seen that in all cases of vague wording giving rise to litigation, that is what the contract amounts to; it confer unfair advantages to one of  the parties, it is unequitably "powerful" in serving someone's interests.

Comment: I can't find _contract open to interpretation_ used as an obvious term (compound, or even strong collocation) in the first linked article. The example, if it exists, should be quoted more fully. As it stands, 'contract that could become too powerful because of vague wording' seems a better answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is true that the combination "contract open to interpretation" is not found in print, but if you had to find something in print in order for it to have meaning the description of new concepts would be impossible. You do find however such sentences as "The rule book is always open to interpretation." , which I find quite natural. The construction "a (rule) book open to interpretation" is hence immediate; then,  is not a contract, by and large,  nothing else than  some sort of rule book? From this and the principle of compositionality, it seems that the term is obvious.

Comment: I'm saying that free combinations (as opposed to collocations or compounds, or fixed phrases) do not constitute proper answers on ELU. We have dropped to offering writing advice, rather than addressing standard constructs.

Comment: I agree that ambiguous could be used to describe the contract, but what I was looking for was more like "ambiguous, therefore, could be abused". I believe "overly broad" or "overbroad" as suggested by two other members matches exactly what I'm looking for. Please let me know if you have something that matches that description more closely. Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

An important element in a legally binding contract is ***consideration***, which is defined as the value to each party that accrues from agreeing to the contract.

Let's say, for example, a neighborhood urchin contracts with Mr. Smith, a neighbor, to mow Mr. Smith's lawn, "when needed," during the months of June, July, August, and September of 2021, in exchange for $100 a month, to be paid on the last day of each specified month. The consideration for the urchin is the agreed-upon wage, and the consideration for Mr. Smith is having a neatly manicured lawn he can be proud of.

The urchin and his neighbor draw up a contract, and they both agree to it. Unfortunately, from Mr. Smith's point of view, the urchin shows up just once a month to cut the grass when the grass is almost a foot high!. Mr. Smith refuses to pay the kid because he (or she) did not cut the grass "when needed," which according to Mr. Smith is when the grass is an inch high.

However, just because their definitions of "as needed" are different does not mean Mr. Smith is no longer obligated to pay the kid a hundred bucks each month. Why? Because the definition of "as needed" was ***not*** specified in the contract. Had each party agreed in advance to what the definition of the words "as needed" meant--namely, an inch high, Smith would not have been obligated to pay up. Unfortunately (from Smith's perspective), he's still on the hook for a hundred bucks!

While doing so may seem unfair from Smith's point of view, the kid, from his perspective, has fulfilled the specified terms of the contract, even though the wording of the contract was overly broad and the wording vague, particularly on the meaning of the words "as needed."

In conclusion, then, my suggestion for the term that describes this kind of contract is ***"overly broad"*** (as "anonymous," above, suggested in his or her answer). The overly broad terms of the contract do give the kid an unfair advantage and give him more "power" (your term) in the contract, but that does not void the contract. Mr. Smith must pay.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I agree, overly broad or overbroad match exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! Have fun on the Stack Exchange, Hal. I've been on several different specialty websites for years, all of 'em on the Stack Exchange. I also contribute writing to Quora. Don